# Stata: How to find firms which changed the status in the time-series dataset

Tags: statistics, stata, economics

I have a data set containing information about different firms' performance in time. It has variables: firm id, year, firm's exporting status (basically, 1 if it is exporter). I want to know how many companies (in a specific group, during specific time interval) made a exporting decision, e.g. changed  exporting status from 0 to 1. I would like to avoid brute force approach by conversion to csv and then parsing by python script.

Comment: Without some attempt at code, this question is a poor fit for a programming forum. Also, research effort appears minimal here: this is an FAQ: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/listing-observations-in-group/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way that uses lag operators:

```
clear

input firm_id   t   exp
0   1   0
0   2   1
1   1   0
1   2   1
1   3   1
2   1   0
2   2   1
2   3   0
3   1   1
3   2   1
4   1   0
4   2   0
end

xtset firm_id t
gen start_exp = cond(exp==1 & L.exp==0,1,0)
bys t: sum start_exp
```

Comment: `cond()` is harmless, but unnecessary. It could be `exp==1 & L.exp==0`.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer You are absolutely correct, but I find the `cond()` easier to read, especially k months down the road.